# Do I have to constantly create a new object or is there a better design pattern?

Tags: java

So I have 4 classes, and they're all aspects of a bank account.

```
    checkingAccount checking = new checkingAccount();
    savingsAccount savings = new savingsAccount();
    Customer customer = new Customer("Bob","Doe","555-555-5555","128 Street Avenue");
    Account accountOne = new Account(2000,"100239",checking,savings,customer);
```

In the above code you can see me create a checking, savings, and customer object prior to inserting them into the account object.

Since this is supposed to be a "bank account" class its going to have millions of customers, my question is do I  have to constantly create these objects everytime a new customer joins my bank?

theres surely a better way to do this correct?

Comment: What would be "better"?  Shouldn't ever account be separate and severed (e.g. instantiated; `new`ed-up; created) from every other account in your bank?

Comment: Yes, but it seems wrong to constantly paste this code over and over everytime a new customer joins, Im assuming this is where databases come in but assuming we're not using one would this be the way to do it? just constantly make new objects ?

Comment: If you're going to have millions of customers, then where are you storing those millions of customers' data? It's important to remember that objects in a programming language are *representations* of things that exist outside of your program. When you type `new Person` you don't literally cause a new person to be born; likewise when you type `new Customer` you don't literally cause a new customer to exist. Your question is really about the *lifecycle* of these objects, and that depends on exactly what they represent. What does it *mean* for a checking account or a customer to exist?

Comment: I suppose then that there's some missing context here.  Ideally, you're creating a new instance for every new customer but you're usually doing this either on an input-loop basis (with `Scanner`s and such) or reading in from a file.  What I think I'm missing then are requirements; how many of these do you have to create and how are you being asked to create them?

Comment: I see.... would this information be put in a database and when arithemtic is performed on that specific user like withdrawal or deposit the object gets created with the variables from the database? then put back? I don't need to have a million objects to account for a million people correct?

Comment: To elaborate on what Makoto said: the comment above says "I'm assuming this is where databases come in", but a database is just a special case of data *storage*. In a simple program, you can use a plain text file for data storage, or even simpler, you can say that the data "storage" is the brain of the user who is typing in new data into the console. In all those cases the data store is "external" to your code; you need to read input and then construct objects to represent those external realities.

Comment: I would very much assume indeed that you have a database or some other form of storage. Otherwise, what happens to those millions of bank accounts if your app crashes if you keep everything in memory?